# Execução de processos em background com Django Python

Tags: python, django, processo

Tenho um sistema web baseado em Django (Python). Neste app preciso mostrar alguns valores dinâmicos vindos de um dispositivo remoto, na qual preciso realizar alguns pedidos a cada 2 minutos para logar os valores no banco de dados e gerar algumas estas ticas como Média.
Existe alguma forma de rodar um processo junto com o server e realizar esse log de tempos em tempos? 
O Celery seria aplicado nesse caso?

Comment: Veja se [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213592/7412) ajuda.

Comment: Depende muito da complexidade do projeto se precisar utilizar muitas tarefas Celery seria mais indicado
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.schedules.html

Comment: como é vindo os pedidos do dispositivo remoto ?